# Pandas Read Excel TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Im getting this TypeError while trying to import .xlsx file with pandas read_excel (using openpyxl as the engine).

[XLSX File](https://filebin.net/b66u8z2ml48hrgxx)

It only happens to this .xlsx file, while other .xlsx files didn't cause any error.

Packages that im using:

1. pandas 1.2.3
2. openpyxl 3.0.7

Line where the error occurs:

```
df = pd.read_excel('2904-1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-76e982c0b69c> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_excel('2904-1.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    297                 )
    298                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 299             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    300 
    301         return wrapper

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, storage_options)
    334     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
    335         should_close = True
--> 336         io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
    337     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    338         raise ValueError(

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine, storage_options)
   1129         self.storage_options = storage_options
   1130 
-> 1131         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
   1132 
   1133     def __fspath__(self):

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    473         """
    474         import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
--> 475         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
    476 
    477     @property

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer, storage_options)
    389             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
    390             self.handles.handle.seek(0)
--> 391             self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
    392         elif isinstance(self.handles.handle, bytes):
    393             self.book = self.load_workbook(BytesIO(self.handles.handle))

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    484         from openpyxl import load_workbook
    485 
--> 486         return load_workbook(
    487             filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
    488         )

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, keep_links)
    315     reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
    316                         data_only, keep_links)
--> 317     reader.read()
    318     return reader.wb

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read(self)
    276         self.read_manifest()
    277         self.read_strings()
--> 278         self.read_workbook()
    279         self.read_properties()
    280         self.read_theme()

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in read_workbook(self)
    148         wb_part = _find_workbook_part(self.package)
    149         self.parser = WorkbookParser(self.archive, wb_part.PartName[1:], keep_links=self.keep_links)
--> 150         self.parser.parse()
    151         wb = self.parser.wb
    152         wb._sheets = []

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\workbook.py in parse(self)
     47         src = self.archive.read(self.workbook_part_name)
     48         node = fromstring(src)
---> 49         package = WorkbookPackage.from_tree(node)
     50         if package.properties.date1904:
     51             self.wb.epoch = CALENDAR_MAC_1904

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
     81             if hasattr(desc, 'from_tree'):
     82                 #descriptor manages conversion
---> 83                 obj = desc.from_tree(el)
     84             else:
     85                 if hasattr(desc.expected_type, "from_tree"):

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in from_tree(self, node)
     83 
     84     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
     86 
     87 

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     83 
     84     def from_tree(self, node):
---> 85         return [self.expected_type.from_tree(el) for el in node]
     86 
     87 

c:\users\roby\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py in from_tree(cls, node)
    101                 attrib[tag] = obj
    102 
--> 103         return cls(**attrib)
    104 
    105 

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

**Note:**
Editing the file manually beforehand is not an option because im parsing it directly after the file downloaded by the program.

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently openpyxl doesn't support this kind of xlsx, yet. https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1662

Comment: Is there a way to modify the file so it doesn't cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Provide the complete file path rather than just the file name!

Because when I run the following command in Pycharm, there was no error!

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_excel('H:\jcar\Jcar\Abanca.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
print(a)
```

Comment: Already tried it, doesnt seems to be the case.